# How can I convert the result of a `$divide` Operator to an C# Int?

Tags: c#, mongodb

Our team is moving to DocumentDB from MongoDB and we have noticed that the `$ceil` arithmetic operator is not supported on DocumentDB. Our team is trying to rewrite the existing code so that we perform the ceil operation in code (i.e. `Math.Ceiling` in C#).

I would like to convert the result of a `$divide` operation to an int:

```
var lastPage = new BsonDocument("$divide", new BsonArray { { "$totalCount.total" }, { pageSize } }); // lastPage = {{ "$divide" : ["$totalCount.total", 100] }}
var result = Math.Ceiling(lastPage.AsDouble);
```

Currently, I am getting this error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument' to type 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDouble'.
   at MongoDB.Bson.BsonValue.get_AsDouble()
   at Rushmore.Data.API.Logic.WellLogic.PagingStage(Int32 page, Int32 pageSize) in D:\_Code\...WellLogic.cs:line 88
   at Rushmore.Data.API.Logic.WellLogic.PagedWellIdsWithoutFilter(Reviews review, String idField, Int32[] filterIds, Nullable`1 page, Nullable`1 pageSize) in D:\_Code\...\WellLogic.cs:line 195
   at Rushmore.Data.API.Logic.WellLogic.GetPagedCollectionData(Reviews review, String idField, String collectionName, IReviewQueryOptions queryOptions, Nullable`1 page, Nullable`1 pageSize, String filter) in D:\_Code\DataAPI\Rushmore.Data.API\Logic\WellLogic.cs:line 537
   at Rushmore.Data.API.Controllers.WellsController.DPRTDData(Nullable`1 page, Nullable`1 pageSize, String lengthUnits) in D:\_Code\...WellsController.cs:line 31
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object )
```

I understand why the error is thrown - the value stored in `lagePage` is a BsonDocument and which in itself cannot be casted to Double. However, I am not sure what would be the correct way to extract the result of the `$divide` operation and cast that to double so I can perform `Math.Ceiling` on it.

I am new to Mongo query language.

Comment: `BsonDocument.AsDouble` doesn't sound right.  Shouldn't it be `BsonValue.AsDouble`?

Comment: Hi, thank you! Yes, you are correct. It does not sound right. However, I am not sure how to reference the result of the `divide` operation from the BsonDocument